Friction for circular object
Is it true that the friction for all circular objects that are in rolling motion is zero since the point of application is on the instant centre of rotation where the velocity is zero
If thats the case, how come it doesn't roll infinitely when there's no force to counteract its movement

Do you mean for a circular object in pure rolling?

yea thats what i meant

This question is similar to: What is the cause of rolling friction? & why is it less than sliding friction?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
